# Best options to call a web service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, web-services

I am working on one application where I have to call web service for getting server response. However i have give two options to do this

A) **Use different services to get different responses.** (e.g. For getting list of product-A use service like 'getProductAList' & to get list of product-B user service like 'getProductBList'  etc. )

B) **Use only one service to get all required responses from service.** (A single  service to get list of product-A & product-B like 'getAllProductList' etc. )

My query is

1) Which option should be the best one to implement & why?

2) Which one is the best way as far as speed,efficiency,flexibility & performance?

It would be nice if someone can help me out to differentiate between these two. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused; you say at the start you are developing a web services client but then ask for advise about how many services to provide...

Comment: I was talking about way of calling a web services  not developing a web services my friend.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your best option would be something like this:

getProduct/ProductA

getProduct/ProductB

getProduct/ProductID

So essentially you have a service called GetProduct in which you specify a unique ID or name of the Product.
If you have separate services like getProductA, getProductB and you realize you need to change something in your service, you will have to correct ALL the services. Also, this isn't really a scalable model.

I've not really worked with *really* large amounts of data in a service but I think the method I've mentioned above would be a good way to go for a normal webservice.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to write a client for your web services. This is purely depends on usage of the data after fetching in your application.

**Long answer:**

**A)Use different services to get different responses:**  If you need only Product-A and later you need product- B data or vice versa, you can go for separate web services calling and you will get separate response according to the service request.

Note:This is less complex when compared to other approach.

**B) Use only one service to get all required responses from service.** Again this is also same thing as like "A" point. For more clarity I am giving basic example, There is a button in your screen once user click on it you need to show Product-A and Product-B information, inn this situation you better to call one service and fetch all data at one go is good choice.

Note:Depends on your architecture. you need to differentiate product-A, Product-B after fetching data.

**1) Which option should be the best one to implement & why?**

This is all about how your application architecture was made.

**2) Which one is the best way as far as speed,efficiency,flexibility & performance?**

**Speed wise & Efficiency:** Calling two deferent different services Asynchronously and concurrent  will be effective.

**Flexibility:** This is my personal experience, I used to get it with two different services and i will differentiate all the data once  fetch in my application.

**Performance:** It's depends on the data your fetching from the services, In this case memory is coming into picture. In your case if your Product-A and Product-B is small you can choose either "A" or "B" but if it is huge data I Suggest "A" approach.

**Conclusion**: Your own have to take a decision according to the situation using above points.

Comment: Thanks ajay for the information. Actually i am using syncing process to get the updated response after login to update the app data. Where I have used option A to get data. I have achieved this by calling multiple  services & in case  of  any loss in connection i   can only call that service which is used for getting updated response. I have done this with maintaining last sync date for each service call which will get updated once response will come from server. This way i do not  have to call all  web services again  to get updated response every time. What do you think on this.

Comment: Any thing related to update of data better to work with Async instead of sync to avoid freezing or blocking of main thread.